# Form data from ReactJS AJAX call is not received in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api, rest

Here is my ReactJS code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

const API_PATH = "https://localhost/testapi/contacts/myapi.php"

class Createform extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={

      Name:"", //initial state of id Name
      Class:"",
      Data_sent:"False"

    };
  }

  handleFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //stops the page from reloading
    // console.log(this.state)
  fetch(API_PATH)
  .then(response =>console.log(response))
  .then(data => console.log(data));

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        
       <form className="form_temp">
         <label style={{marginRight:"10px"}}>First Name</label>
         <input type="text"  value={this.state.Name} id="Name" onChange={data => this.setState({Name: data.target.value})}></input>
         <br/>
         <label style={{marginRight:"10px"}}>Class</label>
         <input type="text"  value={this.state.Class} id="Class" onChange={data => this.setState({Class: data.target.value})}></input>
         <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Submit" />
        </form>

      </div>
    )
     
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Createform/> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is my PHP rest API code

```php
<?php 

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Content-type:application/json");
    
    $rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($rest_json);
    
    if($data){
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "Success"));
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "Failed"));
    }

        

?>
```

When I press the submit button in my ReactJS webpage, I am getting `{"status":"failed"}` as a JSON response, I don't know why the form data is not going to the PHP API when the submit button is pressed.

I only get the response from...

```php
echo json_encode(array("status" => "Failed"));
```

...the above statement, but I need the `{"status":"success"}` response.

Comment: You aren't sending any JSON body, so of course you also won't receive any, and `if($data)` won't be true.

Comment: oh..yeah , LOL didnt notice that

Comment: can u make correction to the code

Comment: can u tell me the code to send the json data from fetch method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending any body in your request, which means you also won't receive any, which means `if ($data)` will never be fulfilled.

It seems you expect the form data to be sent in the request as JSON body. This is not something that will happen automagically, you have to do it yourself.

Take a look at [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). You can initialize it with a form and it will take the values from the fields. You can then convert the values to an object using `entries` and `Object.fromEntries` or by manually iterating over them.

You can then send the data in your `fetch` call.

```js
const formData = new FormData(theForm)
const formDataObject = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())

fetch(API_PATH, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formDataObject),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then( ... )
```

Note that here I'm referring to a variable `theForm` which has to be a reference to the `<form>` element. If you'd change your listener to listen on the `submit` event of the form and not the `click` event of the button, you could simply use `event.target` here.

For more info and a full tutorial, see [this](https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/get-form-values-as-json) and [this](https://gomakethings.com/serializing-form-data-with-the-vanilla-js-formdata-object/) article.